# Trying to set up a file server

Tags: server, samba, gedit

So I'm exceptionally new to uBuntu/Linux in general. I've done the install of Linux Mint 15 onto one VM for PoC and then I figured how hard can it be to set up a File Server for this?

I've gotten past the installation and at one point could get through GEDIT, but now that won't work. When I try to run GEDIT, I get:

> Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such
>   file or directory Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection
>   refused
>
> Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

I tried gksu gedit and that does work (same thing).

To get to where I am now, I followed:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-setup-Samba-file-server/

I'm struggling with all of this; it's all very new, but I'm just trying to get back in to see what happened. I can't find the Share on my Linux Mint VM. I can find the FS luckily though.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are experiencing is because you are trying to run a GUI application on a non-GUI terminal without a `DISPLAY` env variable set.

If you can use a visual terminal (like one you can drag around a desktop), use that instead and try `sudo gedit` or whatever you need to do.

If you are stuck with a tty terminal, or some non-GUI based terminal, try `sudo nano` to edit files instead of `sudo gedit`.

You can also try running `export DISPLAY=:0`. This will tell the non-GUI terminal where to display any GUI application windows (Display :0 is the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> display).

Comment: Also try `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.